# Using RDF statements as body in Web Annotation Data Model?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, protege

I am trying to use [Web Annotation Data Model (WADM)](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/) in order to add provenance information on RDF statements.

To clarify things, each RDF statement (typical subject-predicate-object triples) in my ontology has been created based on knowledge provided on a specific free-text snippet. I want to create a WADM `Annotation` on each RDF statement, having the **RDF statement itself** as a `Body` and pointing to the respective free-text snippet as a `Target`.

Pointing to the free-text snippet as a target is clear to me using [Text Quote Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/#text-quote-selector). However, I cannot seem to find an example of annotating a free-text code with RDF statements per se.

Can anybody point me to an example on how could this be done with Protege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a workaround by annotating the statements (e.g. an ObjectPropertyAssertion) with an annotation using "hasTarget" as the annotation property.

For example, if I want to use the RDF statement `<Subject, Property, Object>` to annotate a target pdf located somewhere in the internet, I would use the following rationale:

```
<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
        <Annotation>
            <AnnotationProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasTarget"/>
            <AnonymousIndividual nodeID="_:genid-f7b71d4c-657e-40bc-bc69-31fc3af8b603"/>
        </Annotation>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="<Predicate>"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="<Subject>"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="<Object>"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>

<AnnotationAssertion>
    <AnnotationProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasSource"/>
    <AnonymousIndividual nodeID="_:genid-0d456ba2-52b9-470d-ad70-efafbc06d261"/>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">source_url</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>

<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasSelector"/>
        <AnonymousIndividual nodeID="_:genid-f7b71d4c-657e-40bc-bc69-31fc3af8b603"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>

<ClassAssertion>
        <Class IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#TextQuoteSelector"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
</ClassAssertion>

<DataPropertyAssertion>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#exact"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">some text</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>

 <DataPropertyAssertion>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#prefix"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">some prefix</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>

<DataPropertyAssertion>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#suffix"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">some suffix</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
```

It can be done in protege by annotating a statement using the "@" symbol on the right of each property assertion (namely the original `<Subject, Property, Object>` statement), in the "Property assertions" view.

I am not really sure that it is fully compliant but it seems Ok to me.

Hope it is helpful for others too.

Edit: Full version of an example ontology, as requested, directly produced by protege in OWL/XML format.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/example"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     ontologyIRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/example">
    <Prefix name="" IRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/example"/>
    <Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    <Prefix name="xml" IRI="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
    <Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
    <Import>http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#</Import>
    <Declaration>
        <AnnotationProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasSource"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasSelector"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#exampleIndividual2"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#prefix"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <AnnotationProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasTarget"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#suffix"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#exampleIndividual"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#exact"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="#exampleProperty"/>
    </Declaration>
    <ClassAssertion>
        <Class IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#TextQuoteSelector"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
    </ClassAssertion>
    <ObjectPropertyAssertion>
        <Annotation>
            <AnnotationProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasTarget"/>
            <AnonymousIndividual nodeID="_:genid36"/>
        </Annotation>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="#exampleProperty"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#exampleIndividual2"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#exampleIndividual"/>
    </ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <ObjectPropertyAssertion>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasSelector"/>
        <AnonymousIndividual nodeID="_:genid36"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
    </ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <DataPropertyAssertion>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#exact"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">some text</Literal>
    </DataPropertyAssertion>
    <DataPropertyAssertion>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#prefix"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">some prefix</Literal>
    </DataPropertyAssertion>
    <DataPropertyAssertion>
        <DataProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#suffix"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="#selector_1"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">some suffix</Literal>
    </DataPropertyAssertion>
    <AnnotationAssertion>
        <AnnotationProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasSource"/>
        <AnonymousIndividual nodeID="_:genid36"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">source_url</Literal>
    </AnnotationAssertion>
    <AnnotationAssertion>
        <AnnotationProperty IRI="http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasSource"/>
        <AnonymousIndividual nodeID="_:genid37"/>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">source_url</Literal>
    </AnnotationAssertion>
</Ontology>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.2.8.20170104-2310) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

Answer (score 1):

WADM does not restrict you in what `body` could be. According to [anno.jsonld](http://www.w3.org/ns/), `body` should be expanded to `oa:hasBody`. 
The [declaration](http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#hasBody>) of `oa:hasBody` does not restrict its `rdfs:range`.

```
oa:hasBody a rdf:Property ;
  rdfs:label "hasBody" ;
  rdfs:domain oa:Annotation ;
  rdfs:isDefinedBy oa: .
```

Thus, you could use [rdf:Statement](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_reificationvocab):

```json
{
  "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld" ,
  "id": "http://example.org/annotation12345",
  "type": "Annotation",
  "body": {
    "id": "http://example.org/statement12345",
    "type": "rdf:Statement",
    "rdf:subject": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Great_Britain",
    "rdf:predicate": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/capital",
    "rdf:object": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/London"
  },
  "target": {
    "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London",
    "selector": {
      "type": "TextQuoteSelector",
      "exact": "London is a capital of Great Britain",
      "prefix": ". ",
      "suffix": ". "
    }
  }
}
```

---

---

> Can anybody point me to an example on how could this be done with Protege?

Protégé is not an RDF editor. RDF is an abstract syntax for OWL serialization. JSON-LD might be used as a concrete syntax for RDF serialization.

However, *if you want to use Protégé as an RDF editor*, the ontology below will be serialized into JSON-LD that is similar to the JSON-LD above:

```
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
Prefix: dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
Prefix: dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
Prefix: oa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>
Prefix: ex: <http://example.org/>

Ontology: <http://example.org/>

# Import: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
# Import: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>

ObjectProperty: oa:hasBody
ObjectProperty: oa:hasTarget
ObjectProperty: oa:hasSelector

DataProperty: oa:hasSource
DataProperty: oa:prefix
DataProperty: oa:exact
DataProperty: oa:suffix

ObjectProperty: rdf:subject
ObjectProperty: rdf:object
ObjectProperty: rdf:predicate  


Class: oa:Annotation  
Class: oa:TextQuoteSelector
Class: rdf:Statement

Individual: ex:annotation12345
    Facts:
        oa:hasBody ex:statement12345,
        oa:hasTarget ex:target12345
    Types: 
        oa:Annotation

Individual: ex:statement12345
    Facts: 
        rdf:object dbr:London,
        rdf:predicate dbo:capital,
        rdf:subject dbr:Great_Britain
    Types: 
        rdf:Statement

Individual: ex:target12345
    Facts: 
        oa:hasSelector ex:selector12345,
        oa:hasSource "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London"

Individual: ex:selector12345
    Facts: 
        oa:suffix ". ",
        oa:prefix ". ",
        oa:exact "London is a capital of Great Britain"
    Types:
        oa:TextQuoteSelector

Individual: dbo:capital
Individual: dbr:Great_Britain
Individual: dbr:London
```

*There are many limitations*. For example, in the ontology above, objects of your RDF statements can not be literals. If you declare `rdf:object` as an datatype property, they can be literals, but then they can not be objects with URIs. The reason of this limitation is that Protégé is not an OWL Full editor, but rather an OWL 2 DL editor.

As a workaround, you could declare and use `rdf:subject`, `rdf:object` and `rdf:predicate` as annotation properties:

```
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
Prefix: dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
Prefix: dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
Prefix: oa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>
Prefix: ex: <http://example.org/>

Ontology: <http://example.org/>

# Import: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
# Import: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>

ObjectProperty: oa:hasBody
ObjectProperty: oa:hasTarget
ObjectProperty: oa:hasSelector

DataProperty: oa:hasSource
DataProperty: oa:prefix
DataProperty: oa:exact
DataProperty: oa:suffix

AnnotationProperty: rdf:subject
AnnotationProperty: rdf:object
AnnotationProperty: rdf:predicate     

Class: oa:Annotation  
Class: oa:TextQuoteSelector
Class: rdf:Statement

Individual: ex:annotation12345
    Facts:
        oa:hasBody ex:statement12345,
        oa:hasTarget ex:target12345
    Types: 
        oa:Annotation

Individual: ex:statement12345
    Annotations: 
        rdf:object dbr:London,
        rdf:predicate dbo:capital,
        rdf:subject dbr:Great_Britain
    Types: 
        rdf:Statement

Individual: ex:target12345
    Facts: 
        oa:hasSelector ex:selector12345,
        oa:hasSource "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London"

Individual: ex:selector12345
    Facts: 
        oa:suffix ". ",
        oa:prefix ". ",
        oa:exact "London is a capital of Great Britain"
    Types:
        oa:TextQuoteSelector

Individual: dbo:capital
Individual: dbr:Great_Britain
Individual: dbr:London
```

[image: Individual views]

Comment: I have just uploaded a full example using OWL/XML format, directly exported by protege. Unfortunately, protege cannot succesfully export my example in Manchester Syntax as it heavily depends on annotation properties of an undeclared entity (the implied target), and I get the message "The Manchester OWL Syntax can lose information such as GCI's and annotations of undeclared entities"

Comment: So where is `oa:hasBody`?

Comment: Nowhere, explicitly stated. You are right, this is a gap in my logic. Having no body is valid in the WADM as far as I understand. However, I totally understand that according to WADM semantics, the triple annotated should be declared as the body of a specific annotation. Still,I cannot find a way to explicitly declare it using protege.

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas, Protege is not a suitable tool for this purpose. However you can load the second ontology from my answer in Protege and play. The "ABox" of RDF generated will be similar to what you need. I really know guys who use Protege as an RDF editor. Also, they use Redis as an triplestore...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Our approaches have different semantics. In your approach, an RDF triple is the body of an annotation. In my approach, an RDF triple is the annotation itself (an annotation without a body). I think that your approach's semantics better fit the WADM model. However, practically, your approach requires adding 5 statements to create an individual representing an RDF statement. This is not a minor issue. I really cannot decide which is better. I will however mark your answer as accepted as it is the one better fitting WADM model (in my opinion).

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas, thank you. Probably you could try another data model. E. g. [Wikidata way](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%3Fupdate%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ865851%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FonProperty%20%3Fstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20prov%3AwasDerivedFrom%2Fpr%3AP813%20%3Fupdate%20.%0A%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3FonProperty%20.%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cfr%22%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: I am familiar with [PROV-O](https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/) (actually used by wikidata) and I already use it in my ontology for other purposes. I think that WADM is more suitable to attribute a fact to an unstructured data source (e.g. free-text source) and this is why I have decided to use it. Thank you once more.